# Problem with showing consecutive numbers after clicking the button

Tags: javascript

I have two files in which I wrote a simple number counter. The point is that when I click, I get an alert with each successive number plus one when I click the button. However, I have a certain problem. Well, here's a code for doing this:

````
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Klik</button>
</body>
</html>
```
```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let count = 0;
function test() {
    count++;
    alert(count);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', test);
```
````

And that code above works. Each time I click on the button, a new value appears, first 1 then 2 etc.
However, this is no longer the case with this code:

````
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="index2.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Klik</button>
</body>
</html>
```
```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
function test() {
    let count = 0;
    count++;
    alert(count);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', test);
```
````

In the case of this code, only one value appears (and this is every time when I click the button), and the only difference between one and the other code is that the variable count with the value 0 in the first code is in the global scope, and in the second in the functional scope. Can someone logically explain to me why the first code works, and the second one does not despite such minor differences?

Comment: Because every time you clicked on the button you trig the function test that initialize a variable count with a value of 0  this variable is specific to the function test. If you try to console.log(count) outside the function test it will write undefined.
In the first one you only add +1 to an existing variable in function test.

Comment: So the point is that each time after exiting this function, test, when I click each time and there is only a value of 1, it is as if this value was resetting?

Comment: Because I want to see if I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because it's creating a new variable named `count` with a value of `0`. It then increments this value, so it's equal to one. Every time the function is called, it creates a new `count` variable.

When you have it in the global scope, it's not creating a variable, it's just updating a global one.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is what I wanted to know. Is there any way to increment the value of count which is in a function range?

Comment: In a functional scope? No, probably not, as it creates its own scope every time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the scope of `count` so that it's declared outside of the event-handler function. The way you have it now, every time you click the button the count is reset to 0, which is not what you want. Try something like my example below which initializes the variable once to 0, then increments on each button click, like this:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let count = 0;

function incrementCount() {
  console.log(++count);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', incrementCount);
```

```html
<button>Increment</button>
```